# Nominal valued dataset in machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining

What's the best way to use nominal value as opposed to real or boolean ones for being included in a subset of feature vector for machine learning?

Should I map each nominal value to real value?

For example, if I want to make my program to learn a predictive model for an web servie users whose input features may include

{ gender(boolean), age(real), job(nominal) }

where dependent variable may be the number of web-site login.

The variable job may be one of

{ PROGRAMMER, ARTIST, CIVIL SERVANT... }.

Should I map PROGRAMMER to 0, ARTIST to 1 and etc.?

Comment: There is no inherent reason to code categories as numbers for a machine-learning algorithm. Furthermore, the ordering of the numbers might confuse you or others into thinking that there is some meaning to it. In following questions, please try to format things more carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a one-hot encoding, if anything.

If your data has categorial attributes, it is recommended to use an algorithm that can deal with such data well without the hack of encoding, e.g decision trees and random forests.

Comment: May I not apply neural network-based algorithms to my problem when categorical attributes are to be considered?

Comment: Decision tree may be what I should use instead of neural network.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the book called "Machine Learning with Spark", the author 
wrote,

---

Categorical features

Categorical features cannot be used as input in their raw form, as they are not
numbers; instead, they are members of a set of possible values that the variable can take. In the example mentioned earlier, user occupation is a categorical variable that can take the value of student, programmer, and so on.

:

To transform categorical variables into a numerical representation, we can use a
common approach known as 1-of-k encoding. An approach such as 1-of-k encoding
is required to represent nominal variables in a way that makes sense for machine
learning tasks. Ordinal variables might be used in their raw form but are often
encoded in the same way as nominal variables.

:

---

I had exactly the same thought.

I think that if there is a meaningful(well-designed) transformation function that maps categorical(nominal) to real values, I may also use learning algorithms that only takes numerical vectors.

Actually I've done some projects where I had to do that way and 
there was no issue raised concerning the performance of learning system.

To someone who took a vote against my question,
please cancel your evaluation.

Comment: But I doubt that mapping real value to categorical feature may result in error in correlation approximation.

Comment: For example, mapping 0 to TEACHER, and 10 to PROGRAMMER may generate false hypothesis that job and weight correlate with each other.